# WooCommerce Remember Checkout Fields

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a page where I send hidden form field values to the WooCommerce checkout page.

```
$my_form = '<form action="/checkout" method="post">';
$m_form .= '<input type="hidden" name="company" value="<%= company %>" />';
$my_form .= '<input type="hidden" name="address" value="<%= address %>" />';
$my_form .= '<input type="hidden" name="address2" value="<%= address2 %>" />';
$my_form .= '<input type="submit" name="mysubmit" Value="Send to checkout">';
$my_form .= '</form>';
```

On the checkout page, I read these values and populate the shipping fields. This works good.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_get_value', 'populate_checkout_fields', 10, 2);
function populate_checkout_fields($value, $input) {
    $company = !empty($_POST['company']) ? $_POST['company'] : '';
    $address = !empty($_POST['address']) ? $_POST['address'] : '';
    $address_2 = !empty($_POST['address2']) ? $_POST['address2'] : '';

    $checkout_fields = array(
        'shipping_company'    => $company,
        'shipping_address_1' =>  $address,
        'shipping_address_2' =>  $address_2
    );

    foreach ($checkout_fields as $key_field => $field_value) {
        if ($input == $key_field && !empty($field_value)) {
            $value = $field_value;
        }
    }

    return $value;
}
```

The problem I am having is that if the user leaves the checkout page and then comes back, the shipping fields are blank again or show the default values if logged in. I need the shipping fields to be blank on first load and then save whatever values get put into those fields, either by the user typing or by using my form page.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution can be with the customer session.
When you use your hook, try to save the values in their session like this:

```
WC()->customer->set_shipping_address_1($address);
WC()->customer->set_shipping_address_2($address_2);
WC()->customer->set_shipping_company($company);
```

Comment: Thanks but I decided to use localstorage to save / load the form field values .